# Number of labelled graphs.

Tags: graph-theory

I'm still beginner in mathematic.

How to prove this formula with induction or another way.

I have: $2^{ n(n-1) /2}$,

if , i sum this i have 
$1+2+8+64+...$ so on.

How  i can prove its equal to formula? $2^{ n(n-1) /2}$

I get this formula from:
how many ways to find labeled graph with $ n$ points.

Help me to solve it  and can you give me some advise to advance my mathematic
thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to prove? I don't see an equation in your question.

Comment: If you are summing this from say $n=1$ to $n=N$, I think there is no nice closed form for the sum.

Comment: Look for Geometric Progression(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression)

Comment: This the equation,
2^((n/2)(n-1))



i'll try to make the proof of it,


this the real question how my homework,



show that an exist as many as 2^((n/2)(n-1)) graph with n point?(proof it).


Sorry, with my english ,if i fault to type .

Comment: @BlackAdder : thanks, but i think this not geometry like usually(if i'm not wrong).

Comment: @AndréNicolas Even though that was (probably) not the question, possibly $\sum 2^{n(n-1)/2}$ can be brought to a closed form using the partial summation technique.

Comment: @flonk: [OEIS A181388](https://oeis.org/A181388) does not give a closed form

Comment: @AndréNicolas yes, my "idea" was to decompose it into $2^{n(n-1)/2}\neq 2^n 2^{(n-1)/2}$ :D thanks anyhow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $n$ labelled vertices, there are $\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}$ potential edges, each one of which may be present or not, so there are $2^{n(n-1)/2}$ possible different graphs.

Comment: can you tell me with simple,concept?

Comment: Each of the $n$ vertices can have an edge joining it to one of the other $n-1$ vertices, but each edge joins two vertices.